# Drop down enquiry

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I need help with this javascript to allow the following to start hidden and on the click of a button show the information. Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* show or hide gadget */
    $('a[rel="hide_block"]').click(function(){
        if ( $(this).parent('div').parent('div').children('div.java_content').css('height')=='auto') {
            $(this).css('background-image','url(images/gadget_dropdown.jpg)');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-image','url(images/gadget_dropup.jpg)');
        }
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').children('div.java_content').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            $('a[rel="hide_block"]').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var objJavaContent = $(this).parents('div.MainParent').find('div.java_content');
                $(this).addClass(objJavaContent.css('height') == 'auto' ? 'gadget_dropdown' : 'gadget_dropup');
                objJavaContent.slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .gadget-dropdown
        {
            background-color: Red;
        }

        .gadget_dropup
        {
            background-color: Yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="MainParent">
        <div class="java_content" style="display: none;">
            test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
            test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
            test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
            test test test test
        </div>
        <div>
            <a rel="hide_block">Show/Hide</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Michael Petridis : this was u r expecting?

Comment: for some reason i cant get this to work i even tried just doing it on a blank html sheet and still nothing?